# What do I put inside a pygame.Surface()?

Tags: python, pygame, surface

```
block1 = pygame.Surface(?,?)
```

when I ran it it gave me an error stating

> ValueError: size needs to be (int width, int height)

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) is a tuple which represents the size of the surface. Therefore, you need to provide these arguments when calling it:

```
width = 600
height = 400
block1 = pygame.Surface((width, height))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pygame.Surface((width, height), flags=0, depth=0, masks=None) -> Surface
```

Reading the [docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) really helps understanding it.